# Azure DevOps `Cannot rebase more than 25 commits`

Tags: git, azure-devops, rebase

I am working on a project in Azure DevOps.

I created a PR that I want to merge with master using the `semi-linear merge` merge-type. This involves doing a `git rebase`. The UI is telling me `Cannot rebase more than 25 commits`.

Where does this limit come from? I couldn't find anything about this in the documentation of MS. Copy-pasting this error message in Google resulted in zero hits. This limit isn't a limitation of git itself. I can't find any related settings in Azure DevOps.

Is it possible to by-pass this limit in a clean way or am I forced to use a different merge-type because of this?

[image]

Comment: Seems to be [under investigation](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/576035/cannot-rebase-more-then-25-commits.html) since a while with no real clean workaround.

Comment: I opted to do a simple merge without fast-forward to preserve history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to by-pass this limit in a clean way or am I forced to use a different merge-type because of this?

Just as Joachim comment, I am afraid there is currently no effective solution/workaround for this issue.

This is a [known issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/576035/cannot-rebase-more-then-25-commits.html) on our main forum for product issue, and MS replied:

> 25 is the default.

And They are trying to raise this limit a bit, like add a registry key to change it.

You could vote and add your comments for that feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've added my suggestions: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/878176/view.html